# How can I copy and paste Arabic in After Effects?

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects, arabic

When I try to copy and paste Arabic text in After Effects, the letters in the words look divided one from the other.

I already had the same problem with Ps and I had to change the settings of the software in “Middle East settings” but I don’t find this solution in the Ae menu´. I discovered a script online, but I think it’s more about typing than copy and paste.

Comment: There seems to be a way with a AE script: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZxX1LCIK6I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a program called **GI-Arabic NOW** (google it it's free) just meant for that purpose.

**How to use:**

1. open GI-Arabic NOW and write your arabic text.
2. adjust the font family and font size as you like
3. when done, hit the button copy **نسخ** and go to Ae
4. hit paste, you will see that pasted words are different but don't worry you will see.
5. adjust the font family and size exactly as you set it the in the first program i.e. GI-Arabic NOW

**Some drawbacks:**
You are limited to the font the program provide.

**Alternatives:**

1. [**Abu Rasheed Text reverser**](http://www.mediafire.com/?n0yjyqvzmmj) support 120 fonts.
2. [**Arabic text reverser**](http://download.cnet.com/Arabic-Text-Reverser/3000-2351_4-75616595.html) support all your installed fonts. No need to install any additional  fonts.

**How to use:**
- open it
- write your text
 - right click and select **convert and copy**  **تحويل ونسخ**
- go to Ae and and paste

I personally prefer GI-Arabic NOW. I don't know why, may be because I use it since 2005 =)

Answer (score 0):

You could paste normally and click hamburger menu on Paragraph panel -> Reset paragraph.

[image]