# Arabic text fields from old projects still give divided words in After Effects

Tags: text, adobe-after-effects, arabic

Now after After Effects supporting Arabic natively, text fields from old projects still give divided words.

[image]

Is there any way to transform them to support Arabic? or any work around, like creating new text and copy all effects from old text to the new one?

Any new Solution in **After effects 2018** ??

Comment: related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57520/how-can-i-copy-and-paste-arabic-in-after-effects

Comment: If After Affects recently added native Arabic support, how did you type out the Arabic before this feature?

Comment: in an old text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new text field (support arabic), then copy the "Source Text" and past it to the old one[image]

Answer (score 1):

After reading the question properly this time for After Effect try this

https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/2/844801

Quote:

1. Copy the effects from the old layer's effects palette, select the new layer and paste. Not all settings will survive the paste -- so check.
2. Select the effect keyframes from the old layer, copy and paste to the new layer.
3. Select the old layer's animated properties (select the property names in the timeline), then animation>save preset, name it and save it. Next, select the new layer, and animation>apply recent preset -- the one you just made.

Comment: a lot of settings not working

Answer (score 1):

This may be worth a try:

[eMashq.com](http://www.emashq.com/) is an online Arabic calligraphy tool, and there is a [trial version](http://store.winsoft-international.com/downloads/free-downloads/free-trials.html) for download. You can possibly have success by doing a copy and paste of the old text into this, and it may convert the text to something that can be applied to your new document.

They also have Arabic text software that works directly with Adobe InDesign or Illustrator that could help if you have those programs.